# Time to live for a Mule message whilst in a VM queue

Tags: mule, mule-cluster

Is it possible for a Mule message to expire (i.e. the container will discard the message) after a configured amount of time (like the JMS TTL property)?
If there is please can you point me to the documentation or example?

Can we use the attribute `queueTimeout` (see http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/VM+Transport+Reference) to achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the queueTimeout attribute does not control the TTL for messages on the queue.  It is used when performing blocking operations on the queue (like dispatching a message or polling for a message).

This feature is not built into the VM transport.  You might be able to accomplish the same idea by setting a message property with a timestamp before publishing it to the VM queue, and then filtering on the message age in the comsuming flow.

Comment: Hello Ryan, Thanks for your answer. I wonder if you had come across the use case described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106969/how-long-will-mule-retain-messages-that-cannot-be-aggregated